# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [<jar>] is not valid in Embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-7

How to fix the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\temp\myApp.jar] is not valid
```

in an Embedded Tomcat application?

I believe I am doing something wrong with the context path but I couldn't figure out how to set it up. Starting the application throw Eclipse work as expected but when I try to run from command prompt I get the error below. I pasted below the two main ways I have tried, App3 and App4 (the error is the same via command prompt). I guess it is not showing error in Eclipse because there must be some pre-defined parameter related to Context that it is making the application run on Eclipse but crashing while triggered from Command Prompt. I have already checked and I am using exactly same JDK.

I believe the problem is with context because, even when it runs throw Eclipse with second tentative (App4), if I check C:\temp, there is no war at all over there.

One tentative (without setAppBase):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;


public class App3 {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws ServletException,
                     LifecycleException, URISyntaxException {
              String runningJarPath = App.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()                           .getLocation().toURI().getPath().replaceAll("\\\\", "/");

              String contextPath = "/";
              File rootF = new File(runningJarPath);

              Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
              tomcat.setPort(8080);
              tomcat.setBaseDir(".");
              tomcat.addWebapp(contextPath, rootF.getAbsolutePath());

              tomcat.start();
              tomcat.getServer().await();
       }
}
```

Other tentative (with setAppBase to especific folder):

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.net.URISyntaxException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
    import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

    public class App4 {
           public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException,
                         ServletException, LifecycleException {
                  String runningJarPath = App4.class.getProtectionDomain()
                              .getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()
                               .replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
                  String contextPath = "/";
                  File rootF = new File(runningJarPath);
                  Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
                  tomcat.setPort(8080);
                  tomcat.setBaseDir("C\\temp");
//the next line was added along with ***Edited 2
                  tomcat.addWebapp(tomcat.getHost(), "/App", "C:\\temp\\");
//the next two lines commented was commented along with ***Edited 2
                  //tomcat.addWebapp(contextPath, rootF.getAbsolutePath());
                  tomcat.getHost().setAppBase("C\\temp");
                  tomcat.start();
                  //tomcat.addWebapp(tomcat.getHost(), "/App", "C:\\temp\\");//
                  tomcat.getServer().await();
           }
    }
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app >

   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>App</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>App</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Logs from Eclipse:

```
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext setPath
WARNING: A context path must either be an empty string or start with a '/' and do not end with a '/'. The path [/] does not meet these criteria and has been changed to []
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:27 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:39 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:39 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [203] milliseconds.
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'App'
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:40 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'App': initialization started
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:40 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'App-servlet': startup date [Wed Mar 02 15:11:40 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:40 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/App-servlet.xml]
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:41 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/upload] onto handler 'fileUploadController'

...

Mar 02, 2016 3:11:41 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'App': initialization completed in 1609 ms
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Mar 02, 2016 3:11:45 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

Error from command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre>java -jar C:\temp\myApp.jar
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\
bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
Mar 02, 2016 3:15:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext setPath
WARNING: A context path must either be an empty string or start with a '/' and d
o not end with a '/'. The path [/] does not meet these criteria and has been changed to []
Mar 02, 2016 3:15:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 02, 2016 3:15:56 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector

INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 02, 2016 3:15:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal

INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Mar 02, 2016 3:15:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal

INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
Mar 02, 2016 3:15:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal

SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:

Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
```

POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

       <groupId>com.myCompany.myApp.batchs</groupId>
       <artifactId>AuthFileUpload</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <packaging>jar</packaging>
       <name>AuthFileUpload</name>
       <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
       <properties>
              <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
              <tomcat.version>8.0.32</tomcat.version>
              <java.version>1.8</java.version>
              <maven.compiler.plugin.version>2.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
              <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
       </properties>


       <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                     <version>${spring.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                     <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                     <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                     <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
                     <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                     <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                     <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                     <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
                     <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                     <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
                     <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                     <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
                     <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                     <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                     <version>1.3.1</version>
              </dependency>


       </dependencies>
       <build>
              <finalName>embeddedApp</finalName>
              <plugins>
                     <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                           <configuration>
                                  <source>${java.version}</source>
                                  <target>${java.version}</target>
                           </configuration>
                     </plugin>

                     <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                           <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>1.1.1</version>
                           <configuration>
<assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                                  <programs>
                                         <program>
                                                <mainClass>com.myCompany.myApp.batchs.AuthFileUpload.App4</mainClass>

                                                <name>App4</name>

                                         </program>
                                  </programs>
                           </configuration>
                           <executions>
                                  <execution>
                                         <phase>package</phase>
                                         <goals>
                                                <goal>assemble</goal>
                                         </goals>
                                  </execution>
                           </executions>
                     </plugin>
              </plugins>
       </build>
</project>
```

*** Edited 1 - the entire log relate to the tentative 1 (App3)

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre>java -jar C:\temp\myApp.jar
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\
bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
Mar 02, 2016 7:53:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext setPath
WARNING: A context path must either be an empty string or start with a '/' and d
o not end with a '/'. The path [/] does not meet these criteria and has been cha
nged to []
Mar 02, 2016 7:53:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 02, 2016 7:53:14 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSele
ctor
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 02, 2016 7:53:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Mar 02, 2016 7:53:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
Mar 02, 2016 7:53:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].Stand
ardContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [St
andardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [or
g.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@791d05e7]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardConte
xt.java:4928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:5058)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [
C:\temp\myApp.jar] is not valid
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(S
tandardRoot.java:723)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardR
oot.java:684)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        ... 9 more

Mar 02, 2016 7:53:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.
java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardServic
e.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.
java:769)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:345)
        at com.MyCompany.myApp.batchs.AuthFileUpload.App3.main(App3.java:28)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [St
andardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed duri
ng start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:924)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        ... 6 more

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to sta
rt component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:345)
        at com.MyCompany.myApp.batchs.AuthFileUpload.App3.main(App3.java:28)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [St
andardService[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.
java:769)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [St
andardEngine[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardServic
e.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed duri
ng start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:924)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.
java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        ... 6 more

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre>
```

*** edited 2 entire log relate to tentative 2 (App4)

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre>java -jar C:\temp\myApp.jar
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\
bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
Mar 02, 2016 8:04:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 02, 2016 8:04:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSele
ctor
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 02, 2016 8:04:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Mar 02, 2016 8:04:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
Mar 02, 2016 8:04:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext postWorkDirecto
ry
WARNING: Failed to create work directory [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\
C\temp\work\Tomcat\localhost\App] for context [/App]
Mar 02, 2016 8:04:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebX
mlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
Mar 02, 2016 8:04:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Mar 02, 2016 8:04:18 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSe
cureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRN
G] took [187] milliseconds.
Mar 02, 2016 8:04:18 PM org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions <init>
SEVERE: The scratchDir you specified: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\C\te
mp\work\Tomcat\localhost\App is unusable.
Mar 02, 2016 8:04:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

*** Added in 2016/03/03 at 4:30PM (Brasilia Time UTC-03:00)

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
                 ServletException, LifecycleException {
          Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

          tomcat.setPort(8080);

          String strBaseDIr = "C:\\temp\\"; // Files.createTempDirectory("tomcat-basedir").toString();
          tomcat.setBaseDir(strBaseDIr);

          // Option 1 - default-doc-base - doesn't work even in Eclipse
          // String strWebApp =
          // Files.createTempDirectory("default-doc-base").toString();
          // strWebApp is C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Temp
          // tomcat.addWebapp("", strWebApp);

          // Option 2 - it works in Eclipse but "HTTP Status 404 - /upload" when
          // started from java -jar
          // tomcat.addWebapp("",
          // "C:\\STS\\wsRestTemplate\\AuthFileUpload\\target\\classes");

          // Option 3 - passing empty path as you wrote
          // "... the trick is to pass an empty folder ..."
          // same issue - "HTTP Status 404 - /upload" when started from java -jar
          // tomcat.addWebapp("", "");

          // Option 4 - the executable jar was placed in C:\Temp
          // same issue - "HTTP Status 404 - /upload" when started from java -jar
          tomcat.addWebapp("/", "C:\\temp\\myApp.jar");

          tomcat.start();
          tomcat.getServer().await();

   }
```

App-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myapp.batchs.AuthFileUpload" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
 <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
 <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

Comment: paste the whole stacktrace under `at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)`

Comment: I added the entire log for tentative 1. About the tantative 2, I made a small change by basically moving up the "addWeApp(tomcat.getHost..." and commenting two others use of addWeb. After that, in tentative 2, I could start the application via java -jar ... but simply I get a blank page when trying localhost:8080/myRequestedMapValue. Just to put in spot light, if I try both, tentative 1 and 2 via Eclipse, I will open successfully localhost:8080/myRequestedMapValue which will open a very simple index.jsp routed by a very simple controller (@Controller plus @RequestMapping(.. get)

Comment: if the server starts this issue it's solved. Please vote up any response that helped and open a new question with the current issue. Important you specify: your jar structure, the entire web.xml, and the url you are getting a 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc base path must resolve to a folder and in your case is set to the current running jar.

Given that you are running a jar, and the API does not accept a `null` docbase, the trick is to pass an empty folder (so no content is accessible from it):

```
public class App {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(8080);
        tomcat.setBaseDir(Files.createTempDirectory("tomcat-basedir").toString());
        tomcat.addWebapp("/", Files.createTempDirectory("yourwebapp-doc-base").toString());
        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
   }
}
```

You can see [here](https://github.com/brutusin/Brutusin-RPC/blob/master/rpc-tomcat/src/main/java/org/brutusin/rpc/TomcatRuntime.java) a more complex example, allowing running over jar/war or source folder, and automatically opening the browser after startup.

Comment: consider adding the relevant parts of the code to your answer directly. Links will become stale, contents will change etc.

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice

Comment: Idelvall, thanks. Unfortunatelly, I am still stuck. If I understood correctly your suggestion, I should do "tomcat.addWebapp("", "");". Well, I tried it and I exported the executable jar but when I try to open in browse I get 404 error. Kindly, see above the four ways I have tried. I am sure there is some error with context but I can't figure out what to do. I added app-servlet just in case it can help.

Comment: by empty folder i was referring to `Files.createTempDirectory()...` not the `""` context path that is indeed the same as `"/"`. I edit my response to avoid confusion